# Error restart threading.Timer

Tags: python

I saw and read answered questions here on stack and I'm still don't know how to fix it.

I'll glad for any help.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import threading

class TaskManagmentHandler:
    # Handle tasks from server

    MINUTES_TO_FIRST_TASK = 5
    MINUTES_TO_NORMAL_TASK = 20
    MINUTES_TO_FAILED_TASK = 20

    global currentAwaitingTime
    currentAwaitingTime = MINUTES_TO_FIRST_TASK

    def executeTaskFromServer(self):
        print ("hi!")

        self.currentAwaitingTime = self.MINUTES_TO_NORMAL_TASK

        taskThread = threading.Timer(self.currentAwaitingTime, self.executeTaskFromServer())
        taskThread.start()

    # start normal task after 5 minutes
    # start cycled task every 20 minutes (task call itself after 20 minutes)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print ("hello!")
        taskThread = threading.Timer(currentAwaitingTime, executeTaskFromServer)
        taskThread.start()
```

And here is the error I'm having:

```
hello!
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: executeTaskFromServer() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Even when I mark all code in `executeTaskFromServer` and just print 'hi' I'm still having the same problem.

I tried even`class TaskManagmentHandler():` but it didn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `self` (since your code is indented under the method)

```
taskThread = threading.Timer(currentAwaitingTime, self.executeTaskFromServer)
```

But this is what you should do actually, move the code outside the class and create a new object and then call the `executeTaskFromServer` method

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("hello!")
    task_mgr = TaskManagmentHandler()
    task_mgr.executeTaskFromServer()
```

You only need to start the thread once